# How to send back Javascript in PlayFramework controller 1.2.x in Java

Tags: playframework

The browser requests some data, for which I need to send back Javascript which will be executed on the browser.

How do I send Javascript (.js) back to the browser from a Play Framework controller?

Thanks

Comment: How do you intend to use the javascript? As JSON-encoded data? As code to be executed? Embedded in a HTML document?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to send back JavaScript, in your controller, you could do something like

```
public static void sayHello() {
    renderText("alert('hello')");
}
```

Then in your JS function that you use to call the action (using jsAction tag), you just use the  javascript eval function.

So, you code may look like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var sayHello = #{jsAction @sayHello() /}
   eval(sayHello());
</script>
```

Please note that eval is viewed as dangerous, as if someone managed to intercept the request, and injected their own javascript into your code, it would execute this code on the client's machine.

Comment: This is good advice, if you want to know a little more about what happens behind the scenes google ajax, xhr etc.